# Не коллапсируеться fixed header на мобильных устройствах, делаю с bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, header

Создал фиксированный хэдер, по идее должен коллапсировать на узких экранах, вместо этого ничего не меняется, 2 фото так должно быть сам сайт - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVhyJ.jpg должен - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjKNZ.jpg выходит - https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0wza.png

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="color: grey; font-size: 12pt;">
 <span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 
  12pt;">Shumik_UA</span></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    <? if ($_SESSION["is_logged"] == false) {
             require("includes/login.html");
    }
     if ($_SESSION["is_logged"] == true) {
             require("includes/islogged.html");
     }
    ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Проверьте наличие viewport `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">`

Comment: ооо спасибооо!!! напиши в ответ поставлю +)))) помогло)

Answer (score 0):

не был добавлен этот тег в head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```